# Wordpress, Plugin PageSpeed Ninja, warning touch(): Utime failed

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, pagespeed

I am using this plugin [PageSpeed Ninja](https://wordpress.org/plugins/psn-pagespeed-ninja/).
I am getting this warning:

```
Warning: touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted in /content/plugins/psn-pagespeed-ninja/ress/classes/filesystem/native.php on line 121
```

Does anyone can help?
I have tried to change the permission of the file to 777 and to 775 but nothing changed...

Thank you!

Comment: check ownership as well as permissions^

Comment: i do not have access to the server... i'm working on altervista,org for the moment...is there something else i can try?

Comment: `I have tried to change the permission of the file to 777 and to 775` <- this implies otherwise

Comment: I have used the FTP...

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the user PHP runs as isn't the owner of the cache files. The file PageSpeed Ninja tries to update the cache files with the modification time of their originals, and while writing to that file can succeed through group permissions, updating the modification time fails unless issued by the owner. Clearing the cache removes the cache files and recreates them with the PHP user as the owner, so the problem is gone.

Hope that helps.